# Unable to receive $_POST data from other domain

Tags: php, post

am unable to receive `$_POST` data form `https://api.razorpay.com`

after successful payment there is a redirect form `https://api.razorpay.com` with `$_POST` and the redirect URL is `http://safebrowser.tk/payment/verify.php`

**verify.php**

```
<?php

include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/include/config.php");
require_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/vendor/autoload.php");

use Razorpay\Api\Api;
use Razorpay\Api\Errors\SignatureVerificationError;

$success = true;

$error = "Payment Failed";

if (empty($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']) === false) {
    $api = new Api(RP_KEY, RP_SECRET);

    try {
        // Please note that the razorpay order ID must
        // come from a trusted source (session here, but
        // could be database or something else)
        $attrbutes = array(
            'razorpay_signature' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'razorpay_signature'),
            'razorpay_payment_id' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'razorpay_payment_id'),
            'razorpay_order_id' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'razorpay_order_id')
        );

        $api->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attrbutes);
    } catch (SignatureVerificationError $e) {
        $success = false;
        $error = 'Razorpay Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ($success === true) {
    $html = "<p>Your payment was successful</p>
             <p>Payment ID: ".filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'razorpay_payment_id')."</p>";
} else {
    $html = "<p>Your payment failed</p>
             <p>{$error}</p>";
}

echo $html;
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**but in webserver i get no dump value**

```
Your payment was successful

Payment ID:

array(0) { }
```

**but when i try on localhost i get dump values**

```
Your payment was successful

Payment ID: pay_EeJzbCSZQLPap8

array(3) { ["razorpay_payment_id"]=> string(18) "pay_EeJzbCSZQLPap8" ["razorpay_order_id"]=> string(20) "order_EeJyrQD9A7Iqrx" ["razorpay_signature"]=> string(64) "31d210c64f3834751dec82e5d166e7ca92186c2b37d4175e4083832a49f0a548" }
```

i tried adding this to **verify.php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

still i don't get any $_POST value.

> how do i get `$_POST` value from other domain?

Comment: How are you making the POST request?

Comment: i don't make any request, its a call back url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the settings of Razorpay, there might be a setting where you need to allow your safebrowser.tk domain. You might also be in "sandbox"-mode which most often only allow certain dev domains, such as localhost.

Comment: yes am in test mode(sandbox), any idea how i can add my domain to dev?

Answer (score 0):

```
require('config.php');
session_start();
require('razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');
use Razorpay\Api\Api;
use Razorpay\Api\Errors\SignatureVerificationError;
$success = true;
$error = "Payment Failed";
if (empty($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']) === false)
{
    $api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);
    try
    {
    // Please note that the razorpay order ID must
        // come from a trusted source (session here, but
        // could be database or something else)
        $attributes = array(
            'razorpay_order_id' => $_POST['razorpay_order_id'],
            'razorpay_payment_id' => $_POST['razorpay_payment_id'],
            'razorpay_signature' => $_POST['razorpay_signature']
        );
        $api->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attributes);
    }
    catch(SignatureVerificationError $e)
    {
        $success = false;
        $error = 'Razorpay Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
if ($success === true)
{
    $payment = $api->payment->fetch($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']);
    print_r($payment);
    echo "<br><br><br>";
    $html = "<p>Your payment was successful</p>
             <p>Payment ID: {$_POST['razorpay_payment_id']}</p>";
}
else
{
    $html = "<p>Your payment failed</p>
     <p>{$error}</p>";
}
echo $html;
```

[image: Output image given below:]

Comment: my question is, the callback is called but i don't get any `$_POST` values.

Comment: Sometime I am using $_request to get the data from payment gateway callback parameters. Please use the same to get the parameters.

Comment: here is my demo (test mode) http://www.safebrowser.tk/payment/ and FYI am trying razor pay hosted checkout.

Comment: Also check my domain for test:

https://www.deepaksyal.me/razorpay/

Comment: i tried with above code still no data. this the method am trying https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/hosted/

Comment: Still your call back URL and Cancel URL is localhost. Please change the Callback and Cancel URL.

<input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="http://localhost:8000/payment/test.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://example.com/payment-cancel">

Comment: when i use localhost URL as callback i can get $_POST value, but on webserver i dont get any data. i tried http://safebrowser.tk/payment/test.php no post data.

Comment: Hi Sanoj Lawrence, 

I have done to integrate the code according to your reference URL : https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/hosted/ 

It will be working fine. You can test on my URL : 
https://deepaksyal.me/razorpay/index_1.php .
 
If you need any help in integration. I can help you.